# libevent: timeout event is not triggered

Tags: network-programming, epoll, libevent

I'm writing a program and use libevent.

I add an event

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 10000;
...
...
event_set(&ev, fd, EV_READ|EV_TIMEOUT|EV_PERSIST, callback, NULL);
event_add(&ev, &tv);
```

but I notice that if I replace &tv with `NULL`, namely I don't want a timeout event, then the program works fine, the event `ev` is triggered when the `fd` is readable,  however, if it is `&tv` not NULL, the event is only triggered for the first time when `fd` is readable.

What is the reason for this? is it that the timeout value is too small? 
what is the minimum timeout value for libevent, epoll, select. etc?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about this , [libevent timeout sample](https://gist.github.com/mythosil/1303479)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <event.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256
#define TIMEOUT_SEC 3

void read_handler(int fd, short event, void *arg)
{
  char buffer[BUFSIZE];
  ssize_t read_len;
  read_len = read(fd, buffer, BUFSIZE);
  buffer[read_len] = '\0';
  printf("%s", buffer);
}

void event_handler(int fd, short event, void *arg)
{
  if (event & EV_TIMEOUT) {
    printf("timeout\n");
    //exit(1);
  } else if (event & EV_READ) {
    read_handler(fd, event, arg);
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  struct event_base *ev_base;
  struct event *ev;
  struct timeval tv;

  tv.tv_sec = TIMEOUT_SEC;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;

  ev_base = event_base_new();
  ev = event_new(ev_base,
                 fileno(stdin),
                 EV_TIMEOUT | EV_READ | EV_PERSIST,
                 event_handler,
                 NULL);
  event_add(ev, &tv);
  event_base_dispatch(ev_base);

  event_free(ev);
  event_base_free(ev_base);

  return 0;
}
```

Just remove the code "exit(1)" in line 22 or do something else when timeout.`event` will be always triggered when `fd` is readable.